Neural Network for Chess Move Prediction Fails to Learn Appropriate Output
I'm working on a neural network to predict chess moves based on a dataset of 1,200,000 chess game positions. Despite the large dataset, my model is not learning appropriately, achieving a peak accuracy of only 0.0104. The output from the model does not align with the expected one-hot encoded arrays of size 128, which represent valid chess moves. I've validated my training data and input tensors, but the neural network's performance remains suboptimal. I suspect there might be an issue with my neural network architecture or training process.
Data and Model Details
Input Tensors: I'm using 8x8x12 3D tensors to represent the state of a chessboard, one-hot encoded by 0s and 1s.
Output Tensors: I use 1-dimensional arrays of size 128, also one-hot encoded, where the two '1's represent a move from one position to another.
Dataset and Preprocessing
For the training dataset, I used the 20,000 games Kaggle CSV dataset. I iterated over each game, generating tensor train and result data for each consecutive move sequence, resulting in 1,200,000 data pair move points at the end. I have validated my training data with test cases, ensuring its correctness.
Problem Statement
Despite these preparations, my neural network achieves very low accuracy during training. While I expected some challenges in predicting chess moves directly, I primarily aimed for the neural network to learn basic chess rules from the dataset. My plan was to use post-processing to filter out the most probable valid moves. However, the model's performance is far below expectations.
Questions
Model Architecture: Are there any apparent issues with my neural network architecture that could cause such poor performance?
Training Process: Could there be any problems with how I'm training the model that might explain these results?
Improvement Suggestions: Any suggestions for improving the model's performance to at least learn basic chess rules and produce valid move outputs?
#model class part of code, and dataset fetch game part
class ChessModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            # Convolutional Block 1
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(8, 8, 12)),
            tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

            # Convolutional Block 2
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

            # Convolutional Block 3
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

            # Global Pooling Layer
            tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),

            # Dense Block
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='softmax')
        ])

        model.summary()

        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                      loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        return model

    def train_model(self, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val):
        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=128, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

    def save_model(self, model_name):
        model_dir = r'C:\Users\schul\Desktop\Chess Engine Python\Neural_Net_Models'
        if not os.path.exists(model_dir):
            os.makedirs(model_dir)
        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, '{}.keras'.format(model_name))
        try:
            self.model.save(model_path)
            print(f"Model saved successfully at {model_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while saving the model: {e}")

    def process_games(self):
        all_states = []
        for index, row in self.games_df.iterrows():
            moves_san = row['moves']

            board = chess.Board()

            move_list = moves_san.split()
            uci_moves = []

            for move_san in move_list:
                try:
                    move = board.parse_san(move_san)
                    uci_move = move.uci()
                    uci_moves.append(uci_move)
                    board.push(move) 
                except ValueError:
                    continue

            uci_moves_str = " ".join(uci_moves)

            states = self.split_conversion_one_hot_127_array(uci_moves_str)

            if states is not None:  # Check states not none by prs.
                all_states.extend(states)

        self.all_current_states = []
        self.all_next_states = []

        for state in all_states:
            if state is not None:
                current_state, next_state = state
                self.all_current_states.append(current_state)
                self.all_next_states.append(next_state)
        
        self.all_current_states = np.array(self.all_current_states)
        self.all_next_states = np.array(self.all_next_states)

    def split_data(self):
        X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(self.all_current_states, self.all_next_states, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

        print(len(self.all_current_states))
        print(len(self.all_next_states))

        print("x train e.g. length sizes: ")
        print(len(X_train))
        print(len(X_val))
        print(len(y_train))
        print(len(y_val))


        return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val



It's impossible to get an output with two 1s using softmax activation.
